# WPF C# Bingo - Populate grid with buttons using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

**Hello,**

I have recently started learning WPF and I've decided to make a bingo
game in WPF.

**What I did so far:**

Created grid of 5x5 table (rows and columns) and managed to generate
a working bingo game (using Buttons for the grid) in the code-behind the xaml.cs file with a few classes for the Bingo itself.

I wanted to ask
whether there is a way to generate the bingo card within the UI, the xaml file itself. 
Can't manage to wrap my head around how Bindings work and couldn't figute out a way to generate a 5x5 button grid using them.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding bindings then you're most likely going to have a hard time in WPF. I'd absolutely recommend finding some tutorial and start learning these basics before continuing with anything else. It really isn't that hard ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could honestly just have your program read the xaml.cs, then have your program pick random numbers at random times based on each specified row essentially creating an array-like structure.  As you know, the numbers are (1–9, 10–19, 20–29, 30–39, 40–49, 50–59, 60–69, 70–79 and 80–90).  You are going to bind the data by utilizing constructors.  Think objects when creating specifications for each row.  Here is a the formal teachings of this practice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application#connect-data-to-controls.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for the reply, I will go through the practice!

Comment: I just went through that tutorial page in like 30-45 minutes.  Super helpful, it explains exactly what you're looking for.  You basically want to have the data updated on the bingo table by binding.  The binding is the synchronization of the WPF app / data on the back-end part of it.

Example: B-7 is the number called out, your program checks the board (rows), if event is handled, and the board synchronizes (the bindings) the data that you have or don't have the number.